# Raydium AMM Program Instruction "custom program error: 0x16"

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, raydium

I currently deployed a liquidity pool to Raydium. https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3VbKy14uCGGBNGzCgZTSZwVvNGinVr8PWz1Xhj6PZdL5bAp1yQmSTQVVXaWGjtf7pnruKSKN2WdDPyo8CVksr4VP When I created the liquidity pool I received

```
Liquidity Pool Created: ADbJ4uWMMpMSwdUGvn8EdTN6RSXJoiDwb7P3s1MusYj7
Base Token (LORO) Amount: 50000000000000000 (Decimals: 9)
Quote Token (WSOL) Amount: 1000000000 (Decimals: 9)
Transaction IDs: 3VbKy14uCGGBNGzCgZTSZwVvNGinVr8PWz1Xhj6PZdL5bAp1yQmSTQVVXaWGjtf7pnruKSKN2WdDPyo8CVksr4VP
success
txids [
  '3VbKy14uCGGBNGzCgZTSZwVvNGinVr8PWz1Xhj6PZdL5bAp1yQmSTQVVXaWGjtf7pnruKSKN2WdDPyo8CVksr4VP'
]
```

However, I'm unable to purchase the token as shown in the multiple attempts in for example here https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4Nc2fXvy21ZXb5GweTi5KN25mk35Ai7kQjMtt5NTYYWviKrrCEh3nfzmLyt8fuoyBpRaq7wsLKYaCWDJY2vBmMX5#ix-7 as shown in this transaction I'm getting the following error

```
> Program logged: "Error: InvalidStatus"
> Program consumed: 12734 of 1364002 compute units
> Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x16"
```

this is the script I used:

```
import {
  MarketV2,
  Token,
} from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk';
import { PublicKey, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';

import {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk';

import {
  connection,
  DEFAULT_TOKEN,
  makeTxVersion,
  RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID,
  wallet,
} from '../config';
import { buildAndSendTx } from './util';

type TestTxInputInfo = {
  baseToken: Token
  quoteToken: Token
  wallet: Keypair
}

export async function createMarket(input: TestTxInputInfo) {
  // -------- step 1: make instructions --------
  console.log("Creating market...");

  const createMarketInstruments = await MarketV2.makeCreateMarketInstructionSimple({
    connection,
    wallet: input.wallet.publicKey,
    baseInfo: input.baseToken,
    quoteInfo: input.quoteToken,
    lotSize: 1, // default 1
    tickSize: 0.01, // default 0.01
    dexProgramId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET,
    makeTxVersion,
  })
  console.log('MARKET ID');
  console.log(createMarketInstruments.address.marketId.toString())
  return { txids: await buildAndSendTx(createMarketInstruments.innerTransactions, { skipPreflight: true }) };

}

async function airdropSol() {
  console.log(`Requesting Airdrop...`);
  const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(wallet.publicKey, 5000000000);
  try {
    const txId = await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
    console.log(`Airdrop Transaction Id: ${airdropSignature}`);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${airdropSignature}?cluster=devnet`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function howToUse() {
  console.log("Running howToUse...");

  const loroMintAddress = new PublicKey("5Epi18QgbkAgFksv4Rj8g5e41NyAmokZE87TKT46EWXx");
  const baseToken = new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, loroMintAddress, 9, 'LORO', 'HighOnLoro'); // Update decimals if needed
  const quoteToken = DEFAULT_TOKEN.WSOL; // Using Wrapped SOL as the quote token

  createMarket({
    baseToken,
    quoteToken,
    wallet: wallet, // This should be your wallet Keypair from config.ts
  }).then(({ txids }) => {
    console.log('Transaction IDs:', txids);
  }).catch(console.error);
}

howToUse().then(() => console.log('Completed')).catch(console.error);
```

ANy idea of what it might be?
https://birdeye.so/token/5Epi18QgbkAgFksv4Rj8g5e41NyAmokZE87TKT46EWXx?chain=solana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you're encountering this error is because the LP you've created has an opening time set for 2024/3/28 at 16:22:26 UTC.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that your pool isn't live yet. Looking at the [pool creation tx](https://solscan.io/tx/3VbKy14uCGGBNGzCgZTSZwVvNGinVr8PWz1Xhj6PZdL5bAp1yQmSTQVVXaWGjtf7pnruKSKN2WdDPyo8CVksr4VP), it seems that you've set the open time to `1711642946` which is in about 6 days.

Comment: thanks a ton, where do you see that timestamp?

Comment: I see `open_time: 1711642946`